# Migrating from Spring Boot Oauth2 to Spring Security 5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Today I'm using *Spring Boot OAuth2* to grant correct use of OAuth2 in my project, so I have the following:

1. I have API A calling API B
2. API A generate JWT Token and calls API B.
3. API B validate the JWT Token using two ways: Online (Introspection) and Offline (with RSA keys).

So, migrating to Spring Security 5 I got the following problems:

1. I didn't found any samples (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/boot) using Spring Cloud OpenFeign. All my project use it (Feing) and change to Spring WebClient can be very problematic.
2. Documentation just talk about WebClient (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2client), nothing about RestTemplate or Feign.

Comment: See here: https://piotrminkowski.com/2017/12/01/part-2-microservices-security-with-oauth2/  Section #7 shows how to add an Oauth interceptor to feign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Joe Grandja](https://spring.io/team/jgrandja) wrote an OAuth2 application and the corresponding migrated Spring Security application.

You can check the examples here:

[Spring Security OAuth 2.4 Migration Sample](https://github.com/jgrandja/spring-security-oauth-2-4-migrate)

Also, docs about configuring Spring Security are here:

[OAuth 2.0 Resource Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/jc.html#oauth2resourceserver)